# Run netbeans as pure java (without exe)

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, command-line, cmd

Hi I need to run netbeans as pure java or java with a .bat launcher that means no exe launcher. Is there any pre-written script to do this and if not is there any documentation on what arguments and classpath netbeans requires.

So far I have this:

```
java -Djdk.home="C:\Program Files\java\default-java" -Djava.library.path="\usr\lib\jni" -classpath "C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\lib\boot.jar:C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\lib\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\core\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\modules\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\modules\ext\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\ide14\modules\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\java5\modules\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\apisupport3\modules\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\7.0.1\nb\modules\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\*\*:C:\Program Files\netbeans\*\*\*" -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy="$http_proxy_tmp" -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts="$http_non_proxy_hosts -XX:"+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"  -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense -Dnetbeans.home="C:\Program Files\netbeans\platform13\" org.netbeans.Main --userdir c:\Users\HJED\AppData\netbeans\7.1\ --branding nb
```

however when I run it, it exits instantly with no errors.

Thanks in advance,
HJED

Comment: If you are lucky netbeans on linux/solaris will use scripts to launch. Try there.

Comment: that where I got what I've done so far, however I am not very familiar with linux scripting and the launcher consists of two reasonably complex files some of which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start netbeans using exe
Use  [jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/)   to see  java arguments( classpath, properties )
Create script from it.

jvisualvm is part of JDK. You may already have it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any pre-written script to do this

Yes there is. It's part of your NetBeans installation

Check out the shell script `netbeans` in the `bin` directory of your installation.

That will show you what needs to be done.

**Edit**:

Another option might be to look at the Ant script that NetBeans uses to start a NetBeans (platform) application. As the IDE is also a NetBeans platform application it might actually give you some hints.

The Ant script is located in `harness\run.xml`

It doesn't look easer than the Linux shell script though..

Comment: The shell script is only in the linux installations and I don't have enough experience with linux scripting to convert it to .bat syntax, I have based what I have so far on that script, but I don't understand it well enough to go any further using it.

Comment: It **is** present in a windows installation when using the ZIP distribution (and not the installer)

Comment: Yeah, but the script is a linux script it is not written for windows and as I've said I've already read through it and got as much out of it as I can.